# drop database did not free up disk space

Tags: mariadb

i have a large database in mariadb 5.58. About 10GB. I droped the database but the free disk space did not change.

Take it a while to free the disk space? Or did i need to purge it? How?

Thanks

Comment: What's your `innodb_file_per_table` setting?

Comment: More specifically, what was the value of `innodb_file_per_table` when the table was `CREATEd`?

Comment: Also where are you hosting it?  In RDS, once a EBS drive has been expanded, it can't be reduced.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like there it is not set in my.cnf. Whats the default?

Comment: `select @@innodb_file_per_table` will show you. See [ALTER TABLE ..  ENGINE=InnoDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/#force) for (5.5.X version), `ALTER TABLE ... FORCE` in newer versions.